# How to created an animated status bar

Tags: html, css, animation, statusbar

I'm not sure what you call these things. I'm calling them animated status bars. They're like progress bars but they're meant to indicate the status of something, which doesn't necessarily progress in a continuous fashion. Progress bars are good for indicating the progress of something which continually moves forward and is expected to complete in a small amount of time. A status bar would be good for something like the delivery status of a package. You don't expect the status to continually move as you watch the status bar. Instead, you go to the site to check the status, note where it's at, then leave and come back at a later time. However, they can still be animated. I've seen animated status bars like this one from the Wish site:

http://www.shahspace.com/status-bar/

It animates when the page loads. It starts at the initial status and moves to the current status. Then it stops.

I'm looking for a simple HTML/CSS way of implementing something like this. Does anyone know how something like this is done (I've seen it plenty of times before so I know there is a design pattern for it)? Any examples of code or references to articles explaining it? (It would also be nice to have status check points on the bar.)

Thanks.

Comment: what have you tried so far? It's gone be hard for you to get an answer for this one without any code. There are plenty of examples on google regarding this.

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet. I wanted to see if there was anything out there I could use out of the box. If not, then I'll try my own.